# Any Solution To Converting Apk To 64 bit in Android studio please Example

Tags: android

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.alifbaataa.madniqaida.madaniqaidahpro"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 79
        versionName '13.11.24'
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'


        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters = []
            abiFilters.addAll(PROP_APP_ABI.split(':').collect {it as String})
        }



        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0-rc02'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.carlosmuvi:SegmentedProgressBar:0.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.varunest:sparkbutton:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.bcgdv.asia.lib:ticktock:1.3'
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.mjn1369:prettydialog:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.panwrona:DownloadProgressBar:1.1'
    implementation 'com.mindorks.android:prdownloader:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.henryblue.mxvideoplayer:xvideoplayer:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    implementation 'com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.2.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'


}
```

How can I fix that and convert to 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Did you analyze your apk? Is it not in 64 bit?
There are two ways to convert apk into 64-bit if it is not.
First you did in this build.gradle file. You have made correct changes but if still your APK is not in 64-bit then it means you are using some library that supports only 32-bit. So read document and track from 3rd party libraries you use in your project, replace or modify them to make them supportive for 64-bit architecture

Comment: I also read documentation at least 20 times but don't understand what i do for that to convert 64 bit actually i don't know how to resolve it any example please help me i also trying to convert but still 32 bit any help with example code or screenshot thank you

Comment: You have to look into the libraries you used in app. This is the solution. You have to do little effort to see any third party library you used in your project which only supports 32-bit.

Comment: I thought the issue is with that library: com.henryblue.mxvideoplayer:xvideoplayer:1.2.0. Check its documentation.

Comment: you mean i remove this dependencies
com.henryblue.mxvideoplayer:xvideoplayer:1.2.0
or other method to use please help

Comment: Thank you (Zubaria Ashraf) its work now
when i remove these dependencies then create in bundle apk that work fine thank you very much

Comment: @SehrMubeen its good to hear that you solved your problem but I did not said to remove I told you to go through with the documentation of this library there may be a solution to make it 64-bit compatible. Anyway, you can also use some alternative library to that does not support 64 bit.